# Run Oracle function without access to underlying table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a simple function created in Oracle database
taken from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_bal(acc_no IN NUMBER) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
   IS acc_bal NUMBER(11,2);
   BEGIN 
      SELECT order_total 
      INTO acc_bal 
      FROM orders 
      WHERE customer_id = acc_no; 
      RETURN(acc_bal); 
    END;
/
```

This is created by user A
I want to

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION GET_BAL TO USER B
```

But user B does not have access to underlying table ORDERS

Will user B still be execute the function or will he need access to the underlying table as well?

Thanks
P

Comment: You need to change the permissions for the function.  The correct permissions are `AUTHID DEFINER`.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff that solves my issue!

Comment: @Prathamesh : "Will user B still be execute the function or will he need access to the underlying table as well?" - no, he don't need to access all objects inside function. he only need execute privilege to call function.

Comment: Where were the permissions set? I don't see any `authid` clause, and `definer` is the default.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson check this out http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_authid_definer_rights.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link to the w3schools of Oracle... `authid definer` is still the default, though.